# How can I call a variable in a path in cmd

Tags: cmd

I am working on a batch file, in which I'm trying to store a directory's name in a variable and then recall this variable in the path to be more detailed I'll give an example of how I'm proceeding to it (but it's not working):

let's say we have the following path `C:\Users\user1\Source\file1`

and you need to store user1 in a variable using: `set user_name = %user1%`

and then use it in the path: `C:\Users\%user_name%\Source\file1`

I don't know if my logic is right but what I'm getting as output is: `C:\Users\\Source\file1`

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: did you notice the built-in variables `%username%` and `%userprofile%`? Try `echo %userprofile%\source\file`

Answer (score 0):

In the part where I was setting my variables I shouldn't have placed any spaces nor %

```
set user_name=user1
```